# Did Israelites ever think that Egyptian gods were part of Yahweh's heavenly/divine council?

Tags: angels, ancient-egypt, gods

I came across an article that described how Dr. Michael Heiser shows that sections of scripture such as Psalm 82 talk about the Hebrew God as the head of a divine council of elohim, i.e. gods.  So did the Israelites once believe that the Egyptian gods were part of that council?  or was it just limited to Mesopotamian deities?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Since YHWH and the Bible acknowledge other gods, does that mean that they literally exist?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45155/since-yhwh-and-the-bible-acknowledge-other-gods-does-that-mean-that-they-litera)

Comment: There are no other genuine Gods, as has been discussed here previously. Therefore, since the Egyptian "gods" are not real, neither they, nor any Mesopotamian "deities", can possibly be part of whatever Psalm 82 is discussing.

Comment: Welcome to the group Traildude. @Matthew, the question here is not whether these gods exist, but whether - presuming Dr. Heiser's hypothesis - Israelites at one time thought of Egyptian deities (as opposed to only Mesopotamian gods) as part of the divine council of which the Israelite God was the head.

Comment: @DanFefferman, that's not how I read the question. Maybe you'd like to edit it?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: @Matthew You're right. It's how I understood the intent of the question.

Comment: @Traildude.... I edited your question so that it's not asking if these gods really existed (not really a question for this forum) but whether the bible hints at a time when Israelites believed they did. Please feel free to re-edit... but the question is in danger of being closed as off topic.

Comment: Thanks for your question, Traildude. However, according to Exodus chapters 7:5 to 14:31, Yahweh trampled the believers of the Egyptian gods into the mud of the parted Red Sea. Before Psalm 82 was written, Yahweh kept reminding Israel of that, and warning them not to go back to Egypt or to be influenced by their pseudo gods. He utterly despised those pagan beliefs. No Israelite could ever think Yahweh was the 'head' of Egyptian gods if they believed their Hebrew scriptures.

Comment: Joshua 24:14 tells us that Israelites worshipped Egyptian gods. They never stopped believing in yhwh so it’s logical to assume they felt there was a coalition of gods  in heaven.   Of course  they were punished severities for that

Comment: @DanFefferman, okay, and thanks for the edit! But then, I suspect this would be more appropriate on Mi Yodeya, or even History.SE. The *Christian* answer is, as I noted, "there are no other 'gods'". 

Comment: @Matthew  Actually the Christian answer would be whatever is true of (1) the passage itself and (2) what the Israelites believed.  If the question had also asked what Paul's view was your comment would be perhaps correct.

Comment: @Anne  First of all, they didn't have any scriptures when they came out of Egypt; second, if you read Psalm 82 it's clear that Yahweh was not happy with His heavenly council, so if the Egyptian gods were considered part of His council it doesn't mean they had His approval.

Comment: Okay, Traildude - the last sentence in my comment should have read, "...if they believed what happened to them in being delivered from Egypt, as should have later generations who had that written account." And, just because most of the Hebrews came out of Egypt 'contaminated' with Egyptian idolatry does not mean to say they viewed them as part of Yahweh's heavenly council. Psalm 82 deals with humans on Earth representing God as judges, who should have been delivering God's judgments, but were not, as Jesus pointed out when quoting Psalm 82 in John 10:34.

Comment: @anne Your claim about Psalm 82 is incorrect.  The Psalm reads:
God has taken his place in the divine council;
in the midst of the gods he holds judgment:
We know that this should be translated as "gods" for a number of reasons:  it's talking about members of "the divine council", and the word used is אֱלֹהִ֣ים which is only used of heavenly beings, i.e. pure spirit beings.
Further, if it was talking about human judges then there is no point to the statement "You will die like men" -- if they were men, then obviously they would die like men.  God is rather talking to "the divine council".

Answer (score 2):

> So did the Israelites once believe that the Egyptian gods were part of that council? or was it just limited to Mesopotamian deities?

Colloquial concepts of deities morph over time, and especially whenever paganism takes over, which it almost invariably does in any culture given time, corruption of language and corruption of minds; also concepts can be shared across groups. Abraham did enter Egypt and taught the Egyptians concerning the religion of his God, so in early Egyptian writings it makes sense to see congruence or confluence of their concepts of Deity circa 1800 B.C., later reinforced by Abraham's great grandson Joseph when he became vizier of Egypt. Therefore we ought to expect  to see evidence of such Hebrew influence on the Egyptians, assuming such influence survived subsequent religious and political changes in Egpyt. Originally Osiris may have been an Egyptian rendering of "Jehovah" having similar or identical meaning, in which cause it would almost necessarily be true that He was present in the Divine council. See the [Papyrus of Ani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papyrus_of_Ani) and numerous other depictions of the Hall of Judgment that mesh exceptionally well with Hebrew and Christian concepts of the Judgment and afterlife. (Interestingly the name of pestilent Egyptian pseudo-deity of the underworld, often called "Set" is lexically indistinguishable from a name pronounced "Satan" in modern tongues.)

Obviously no pagan or false deities are part of a Divine council unless in a pre-fallen state, but of course subsequent paganization and corruption of language may easily obscure the original identities assigned to various characters in early Egyptian religious writings and murals.

So it might be an anachronism to say that Israelites believed that Egyptian deities were present in the Divine council, but Israelites did teach the Egyptians about the God of Israel, for which there is abundant surviving evidence in their religious texts. So in that sense technically, some Deities of which the Egyptians were made aware and had some religious writings on, as taught to them by Abraham or his offspring, may have been included in the Divine council.

Answer (score 1):

First, we should clarify that the teaching of Israel's God being the head of a council of gods is not a Christian one. However, there are indeed some scholars of religion - include some who identify as Christians - who see an evolution in Israelite religion from henotheism (the worship of one god while recognizing the existence of others) to monothesism (the belief that only one God exists).

Presuming that ancient Israelites believed that their God was (or once was) the head of a heavenly council, did they include Egyptian deities as well as Canaanite and Mesopotamian gods as members of it? The answer is a qualified "yes." One basis for this answer is that Egypt had dominated Canaan in the period prior to the Exodus and their gods were certainly known there. An article published by the [University of Pennsylvania Museum](https://www.penn.museum/sites/canaan/Egypt.html) states:

> Egyptian imperialism led to a dramatic increase in cultural exchange.
> Many Egyptian bureaucrats and soldiers were stationed in Canaan and
> Egyptians and Canaanites often lived side by side. Musical
> instruments, poetry, myths, weapons, clothing designs - *even gods
> and goddesses* (emph. added) - passed from one culture to the other. Many of
> these influences were long lasting. Scribes in Iron Age Judah
> continued to use Egyptian numbers 550 years after the end of the
> Egyptian empire.

Evidence of henotheistic attitudes in ancient Israel are also hinted at in the Bible, as the OP suggests. A biblical passage that seems to preserve this attitude is found in Deut. 32:

> Remember the days of old,
> consider the years of generations past. Ask your father, he will inform you,
> your elders, they will tell you: 8 When the Most High allotted each nation its heritage,
> when he separated out human beings, He set up the boundaries of the peoples
> after the number of the divine beings; 9 But the Lord’s portion was his people;
> his allotted share was Jacob.

Presuming Israelite henotheism, this passage indicates that, rather than YHWH being the head of the divine council, he was assigned to the people of Israel by a higher deity, called "the Most High" (Elyon). However, according to historians of religion, YHWH eventually came to be seen as the supreme deity and ultimately the only God who actually existed.

**Conclusion**: We can't know for certain whether Israelites ever thought of a heavenly council in which Isis and Ra sat together with Asherah and Ba'al in a meeting where YHWH or Elyon presided. It is possible that Isis was understood to be the Egyptian name of the Babylonian Ishtar or the Canaanite Astarte, for example. In any case, henotheism presumes that only one deity is to be worshiped. That deity for Israel was YHWH. Once the henotheistic principle was adopted, the other gods became less and less important. But Egyptian deities would have been among them.

Comment: In Dr. Michael Heiser's interpretation of Ps. 82 (see [here](https://irp.cdn-website.com/540907fb/files/uploaded/Elohim%201%20PDF.pdf)), YHWH = Elyon (Most High) = God of Israel = the Creator God who rule over the 70 (?) gods of the various nations, including Egypt, Babylon, etc.

Comment: This depends on whether one thinks the Israelites always practiced what the Torah teaches. It's clear that they did not, for they were punished for "worshiping the host of heaven" and following false gods etc. So when scholars like Heiser say "religion of ancient Israel" they mean what the Israelites practiced, not what the Bible instructed them to practice.

Comment: I provided +1 to neutralize the -1 your answer doesn't deserve. I think you're right that there was an evolution from henotheism to monotheism. I also think Dr. Heiser is right that in the Israelite worldview of that period (following the broader ANE conception), there was a real god behind every nation (hints in Psalm 82 and Deut 32:8-9,17, scripture of that era), but Moses taught the Hebrews that their God who delivered them from Egypt was *greater* than Egypt's god: YHWH was the one giving the other gods authority over nations, but they abused their authority by enslaving the Hebrews, etc.

Comment: @DanFefferman  I have to disagree with your first line, "we should clarify that the teaching of Israel's God being the head of a council of gods is not a Christian one"; if the scriptures depict Yahweh as head of a heavenly council, then that's the Christian view -- we don't get to ignore things the scriptures tell us.  And in this instance the evidence is in favor of a divine council (I spent a couple of hours last night listening to Dr. Heiser's videos about this and following along looking up each Bible reference, and I'm convinced.  It also makes sense out of a bunch of things in the NT.

Answer (score 1):

Being a touch pedantic here, nobody can say whether "the Israelites" - as a nation - believed the Egyptian gods were part of a heavenly council that Yahweh had. Now, if anyone can produce ancient Hebrew literature that says the whole nation did, then I will stand corrected and retract my opening sentence.

It does not matter if lots of Israelites, at one time in the ancient past, believed a legend, or a story, or even a teaching from some of their leaders, about pagan deities forming part of God's heavenly council. Nowhere in the Hebrew scriptures is such an idea even suggested. Despite the ancient book of Job speaking about a particular time when "the sons of God" presented themselves in heaven (Job 1:6), it is heavenly creatures who are in heaven who present themselves to Yahweh, including Satan, who had been roaming around Earth. There are no "sons of men" present; there are no gods present, for heaven only "holds" the one Almighty God. All others in heaven are the creatures he created, and Yahweh never created any rival gods!

Isaiah knew that, for from the time Yahweh rescued his people from Egypt to his day, Israel was clearly taught, "I am the first, and I am the last; and beside me there is no God...there is no God beside me, I know not any... there is no God beside me..." Just read Isaiah chapter 44. That was a foundational distinction between Israel and all the nations around them - or it should have been, had they not succumbed to idolatrous influences. But even if any that got many of them thinking pagan deities were associating intelligently with Yahweh in his heaven, the nation never changed that foundational doctrine, replacing it with any new one about other deities (from whichever country they were supposed to be from) being part of Yahweh's divine council in heaven. For the nation to switch to that doctrine would have been national heresy. Yes, many individuals became heretical in their ideas then practices, leading to God's eventual judgment on the nation (exile for 70 years) but thereafter they had finally learned their lesson and eschewed idolatry.

Now, the writer of Psalm 80 lived long before that slide into pagan wickedness, and would know of Job 1:6, so that is the basis for understanding his meaning. Given that no gods were mentioned at that heavenly gathering before Yahweh in Job, nobody can try to 'insert' them in, via some back-door theories. **What does show the meaning comes with Jesus' words about Psalm 80 in John 10:34.** Psalm 82 deals with humans on Earth representing God as judges, who should have been delivering God's judgments, but were not. Yet even those corrupt human representatives were due respect, which Jesus was not even getting, despite being the Son of God!

However, as the OP commented eleven hours ago, ***"in this instance the evidence is in favor of a divine council (I spent a couple of hours last night listening to Dr. Heiser's videos about this and following along looking up each Bible reference, and I'm convinced."*** there is therefore no point in saying anything more because the OP has made his mind up, that Dr. Heiser is right in claiming that the teaching of Israel's God being the head of a council of gods is the Christian one. Those who know the entire Bible teaches that there is only one, true God, the only Creator, the only deity to be worshipped, will continue to beg to differ.